# How to bind composite model using Spring web flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have a Person Object containing an Address object like this:

```
class Person {
   private int age;
   private Address address;

 public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address= address;
}
}
```

And a class Address:

```
class Address{

   private String streetAddress;
   private String city;

 public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getStreetAddress() {
    return state;
}

public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

In my Spring web flow, I have:

```
<var name="person" class="Person"/>
<var name="address" class="Address"/>

   <view-state id="view1" view="qualificationView" model="person">

   <transition on="submitApplication" to="view2"/>
</view-state>
```

My html has attributes:

```
age
streetAddress
city
```

On form submit, I see the "age" attribute getting bound correctly, but the attributes in the Address class are not being set.

How do I make it set all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form:input type="text" path="address.streetAddress"/>
```

And you don't need to define the `<var name="address".../>`. And I think you will have to explicitly initialize `address` in your `Person` to `new Address()`.